# Linq to compare two lists of objects where one object has several lists

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class MyObject1
{
    public  Guid g1;
    public Guid g2;
    public Guid g3;
}

public class MyObject2
{
    public Guid g4;
}


List<MyObject1> list1;
List<MyObject2> list2;
```

I would like a LINQ query that would return all MyObject1 objects in list1 where  MyObject1.g2 == MyObject2.g4 where the MyObject2 objects live in list 2

i have written code that does this in numerous steps but i would think i could do it in one iteration.

so something like

```
var n = list1.Select(p=> p.g2).ToList()

var o = list2.Intersect(n)
```

but now i need to research list1 using o again which is awkward

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534675.aspx):

```
var query = from x1 in list1
            join x2 in list2 on x1.g2 equals x2.g4
            select x1;
```

Or in extension method syntax:

```
var query = list1.Join(list2, x1 => x1.g2, x2 => x2.g4, (x1, x2) => x1);
```

Note that this will only give you the items from `list1` - if you need the corresponding item from `list2` as well, that's simple:

```
var query = from x1 in list1
            join x2 in list2 on x1.g2 equals x2.g4
            select new { x1, x2 };
```

Comment: +1 Jon, I wish you'd stop giving that dodgy extension method join syntax as an alternative though ;)

Comment: @mattytommo - but... I like the extension methods

Comment: @ScottSelby Even for joins and group bys? Eeeeek :P

Comment: @mattytommo: This is a join which doesn't require a transparent identifier. It's *just* a simple projection to one half of the join. If there'd been a more complex `select` clause, I wouldn't have bothered with the extension method syntax - which most certainly isn't "dodgy" in the slightest. (And I'm fine with using the extension method form of `GroupBy` too, where it ends up being more readable, which can certainly happen. There's no need to get religious about "always use query extension syntax for joins and groupings".)

Comment: If there are multiple column which are matching still result is only one column

Comment: @Shrivallabh: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all.

Answer (score 8):

```
var query = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2=> l2.g4 == l1.g2));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var results = 
    from a in list1
    join b in list2 on a.g2 equals b.g4
    select a;
```

This will return all items from `list1` where there exists an item in `list2` with the `MyObject1.g2 == MyObject2.g4`.